# AJAX request cannot pass DateTime to server if using GET method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a form which uses Kendo controls, and when user click the button, an AJAX request gathering these controls' value will be sent to server and download a file based on these criteria. One of the controls is DateTimePicker.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: '@Url.Action("MyGenerateReportMethod")',
    async: true,
    data: getViewModel(),
    ...
});


function getViewModel() {
        ...
        viewModel.DateFrom = $("#DateRangeFrom").data("kendoDatePicker").value();
        ...
        return JSON.stringify({ para: viewModel });
}
```

```cs
public ActionResult MyGenerateReportMethod(MyModel para)
{
   try{
       ...
   }
}
```

```cs
public class MyModel
{ 
    public DateTime? DateFrom { get; set; }
}
```

The above simplified code demonstrate my situation.

I have a POST ajax request to server, which passes a serialized JSON object including a Kendo DateTimePicker Value.

The server side action try to catch this JSON object as parameter and do the stuff which is irrelevant to this question.

---

My question is, for some reason I have to changed the request from POST to GET.
While it works using POST method, it does not work if I change "POST" to "GET".

I checked the request sent in Chrome's Developer Tools, It does sent the JSON object in the following format: (In Query String Parameters section in the Network Tab)

```
{"para": {
    ...
    "DateFrom":"2016-04-13T16:00:00.000Z"
    ...
    }
}
```

However, at server side, `MyModel para` does not seems to catch this object successfully (if I change from "POST" to "GET").  Other fields still can be bound while **all `DateTime` fields become `null`**.

Why is this happening, and how can I change the request from "POST" to "GET"?
Thanks.

---

**EDITED**

Based on some comments / answers, I have tried to modified the AJAX request to the following code, but it is still not working... (Same behavior)

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("SumbitOutstandingReportList")',
            data: getPlanViewModel(),
            async: true,
 ...
}

function getPlanViewModel(){
    var obj = {};
    ...
    obj.DateFrom = $("#DateRangeFrom").data("kendoDatePicker").value();
    ...
    return { para: obj };
}
```

Comment: Remove the `contentType` option and do not stringify the data (there is no body in a GET request) - just use `data: { DateFrom: $("#DateRangeFrom").data("kendoDatePicker").value() },`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried but still not working...

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have updated my code in OP, can you see what have I missed?

Comment: Its just `return obj;` in your `getPlanViewModel()` function (not `return { para: obj };`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Finally, I can bind the DateTime when I use { DateFrom: $("#DateRangeFrom").data("kendoDatePicker").value().toISOString().   Please post your answer...thanks!

Comment: But you noted the request was `"DateFrom":"2016-04-13T16:00:00.000Z"` which is in ISO format :) (will add answer shortly)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yup, that's what I saw, when I didn't remove contentType and still use Stringify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A GET does not have a body, so remove the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` option (does no harm but its only applicable to a POST) and adjust the data so that the ajax call is

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'Get',
    url: '@Url.Action("MyGenerateReportMethod")',
    data: getViewModel(),
    ...
});

function getViewModel() {
    var obj = {};
    ...
    obj.DateFrom = $("#DateRangeFrom").data("kendoDatePicker").value();
    ...
    return obj; // return the object, not a stringified object containing another object
}
```

Note this assumes the value is in a format that matches your server culture, or in ISO format (e.g. the request will be `DateFrom: '2016-04-13T16:00:00.000Z'`)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of, GET method is pass data in a header or url, while json data can not passed through header, change the method of passing data, which is currently in a json format.

You could do like even :

var fd = new FormData();

fd.append('data', yourData);

and send fd as a directly data object, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

GET request has no body, it passes the parameters in either cookies or URL query string, so pass the data you want in a query string parameter like below:

```
var url = @Url.Action("MyGenerateReportMethod",new {DateFrom="_X_"});
url = url.replace("_X_",$("#DateRangeFrom").data("kendoDatePicker").value());

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: true
});
```